# A heap has been corrupted after populating another 2d array

Tags: c++

I am writing a program where I need to take 2 text files and see where the smaller image is inside the bigger one. For this I need to use 2 dimensional arrays. This has all been going fine when I was just using one however now that I have populated the second array with the data from the smaller image I am getting an error saying:

> Unhandled exception at 0x77338519 (ntdll.dll) in  Wheres Wally.exe:
>   0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x773758A0).

I have managed to narrow it down to one line in particular which is when the second array is actual given values

```
//Array Containing Initial Values Of The Base Image
            double* baseImage = new double(largeImageRowSize * largeImageCollumnSize);
            //Array Containing Values Of The Small Image
            double* wallyImage = new double(smallImageRowSize * smallImageCollumnSize);

            //Fill BaseImage with all values from the text file
            baseImage = read_text("Cluttered_scene.txt", 1024, 768);

            //Allocate 36 arrays for each row (so 49x36 arrays)
            for (int i = 0; i < getLargeRowSize(); i++)
                a2dArray[i] = new double[getLargeCollumnSize()];

            //Put data of image into 2d array
            int largeImageCounter = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < getLargeCollumnSize(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < getLargeRowSize(); x++) {

                    a2dArray[y][x] = baseImage[largeImageCounter];
                    largeImageCounter++;
                    //cout << a2dArray[x][y];
                }
            }

            //Fill wallyImage array with all values of the small wally text file
            wallyImage = read_text("Wally_grey.txt", 49, 36);

            //Allocate 36 arrays for each row (so 49x36 arrays)
            for (int i = 0; i < getSmallRowSize(); i++)
                a2dArrayForWally[i] = new double[getSmallCollumnSize()];

            //Put data of image into 2d array
            int smallImageCounter = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < getSmallCollumnSize(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < getSmallRowSize(); x++) {

                    a2dArrayForWally[y][x] = wallyImage[smallImageCounter];
                    smallImageCounter++;
                    //cout << a2dArray[x][y];
                }
            }
```

The line giving the error is within the final for loop

```
a2dArrayForWally[y][x] = wallyImage[smallImageCounter];
```

So obviously this is something to do with where the memory is being stored, but I'm new to C++ and after googling I cant seem to find whats wrong with my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Through trying to solve the error myself I have discovered that the issue arises when the `smallImageCounter` reaches 430. Before that data is stored with no issues

Comment: This seems like the sort of problem that would be easier for you to solve by using your debugger, rather than asking people to guess the problem based on an incomplete fragment of code. Alternatively, you'll need to put together a [mcve].

Comment: Note that heap corruption does not necessarily detect right after the corruption happens. It could detect the corruption minutes later. The corruption could be caused by some other part of your code and only detected now.

Comment: ***that the issue arises when the smallImageCounter reaches 430. Before that data is stored with no issues*** Is `smallImageCounter` greater than the size of the array you allocated? Maybe either `smallImageRowSize` is not equal to `getSmallRowSize()` or `smallImageCollumnSize` is not equal to `getSmallCollumnSize()`

Comment: This is more or less all the code I have, I know its that line specifically that is causing the problem because when I remove it then the first array is able to read as normal. Small image counter has a size of 1764 and the getters for smallRow and smallCollumn directly return the respective variables.

Answer (score 1):

You confused `new double()` with `new double[]`. The first one allocates a **single** `double` and initializes it to the value from the parenthesis, where the second one allocates a dynamic array of `double`s of a size from the square brackets.

Change:

```
double* baseImage = new double(largeImageRowSize * largeImageCollumnSize);
double* wallyImage = new double(smallImageRowSize * smallImageCollumnSize);
```

to:

```
double* baseImage = new double[largeImageRowSize * largeImageCollumnSize];
double* wallyImage = new double[smallImageRowSize * smallImageCollumnSize];
```

Comment: I feel like such an idiot for missing that, however it didnt fix the error. Thank you though I'm sure that would have caused me issues later on.

Comment: @MaxKenney well, you have provided neither the error message nor [mcve], so we can only guess now. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I dont think I understand, I did give the error message I am receiving In the question unless there is a way to receive more information about the error I am unaware of.  I will add the new information I have found from trying to debug but I am not sure it will help in trying to solve the problem

Comment: What you provided was exception description - so there are no compile errors, that's good. If that didn't solve your problem and different exceptions pop up, try to extract the non-working code and ask another question.

Comment: Oh okay, well in terms of different exceptions I get one on the same line as I suspected before saying it has triggered a breakpoint when a breakpoint isnt there. It then opens a new tab in visual studio and displays the message 'wntdll.pdb not loaded'

Comment: ***'wntdll.pdb not loaded'*** Is not really important. You don't want to debug the OS for Microsoft. Walk up the callstack to your code by switching the stack frame in the debugger.